# Write values to a text file with scientific notation

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with a large amount of data in scientific notation, sorted in columns like this:

[image]

I have some VB code that extracts each column of data from Excel and writes each individual column to a text file:

```
    Sub ExportToNotepad()
    Dim wsData As Variant
    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim FN As Integer
    Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Dim myString As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

    lastrow = Sheets("flux2018").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(29, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    path = "C:\Users\bloughj\Documents\NFluxes\"

    For p = 1 To lastcolumn
    wsData = ActiveSheet.Cells(28, p).Value
    If wsData = "" Then Exit Sub
    myFileName = wsData
    myFileName = myFileName & ".txt"
    myFileName = path & myFileName
    For q = 29 To lastrow
    myString = myString & vbCrLf & Cells(q, p)

    FN = FreeFile
    Open myFileName For Output As #FN
    Print #FN, myString
    Close #FN
    Next q
    myString = ""
    Next p


    End Sub
```

It seems to extract the data, but it doesn't put it in scientific notation with 4 decimal places like the source data.  Also, each resulting text file starts with a blank line:

Example:

```
    24
    20000000
    10000000
    5000000
    2000000
    1000000
    100000
    10000
    1000
    100
    10
    1
    0.625
    0.5
    0.4
    0.3
    0.2
    0.1
    0.08
    0.06
    0.04
    0.03
    0.02
    0.01
    0.0002
    0.00001
    1.0515639915552E-05
    3.63926199086599E-04
    1.9676665491577E-03
    1.42654567203907E-03
    5.81606017515438E-03
    1.00247561028745E-02
    1.32534668446465E-02
    1.54728811746672E-02
    1.69472358325774E-02
    1.87875054958548E-02
    4.40254611566843E-03
    2.24021737838812E-03
    2.37656211009138E-03
    3.40419784285222E-03
    7.97308912593133E-03
    9.15215298875479E-02
    7.52308259032017E-02
    0.12439644621192
    0.192207571010406
    0.120888605459018
    0.126903744311048
    0.112336857282057
    5.20321789727604E-02
    1.37510447075413E-05
    56
    20000000
    6430000
    4300000
    3000000
    1850000
    1500000
    1200000
    861000
    750000
    600000
    470000
    330000
    270000
    200000
    50000
    20000
    17000
    3740
    2250
    192
    188
    118
    116
    105
    101
    67.5
    65
    37.1
    36
    21.8
    21.2
    20.5
    7
    6.88
    6.5
    6.25
    5
    1.13
    1.08
    1.01
    0.625
    0.45
    0.375
    0.35
    0.325
    0.25
    0.2
    0.15
    0.1
    0.08
    0.06
    0.05
    0.04
    0.0253
    0.01
    0.004
    0.00001
```

How can I get it to format the output in scientific notation with 4 decimal places, like the original data?  And how do I get rid of the blank line at the beginning of each .txt file?

Comment: Not tested but perhaps try assigning the cell values to a string variable first in the loop (just in a new line above your current statement), then use that variable instead of `Cells(q, p)`. Also, you can add an `If...Then` statement for if it's the first iteration of the loop, `MyString = `Cells(q, p)` else your current statement - that will get rid of the first line being blank.

Comment: `Cells(q, p)` reads the cell's *value* - that is the underlying number stored in the cell, not the formatted version you see in the sheet.  You could either try `Cells(q, p).Text` or use `Format()` to get the output you want.

Comment: Using Cells(q, p).Text fixes the issue with it not exporting in scientific notation and 4 decimal places.  Thanks.

But I'm still getting the blank line at the top of the output .txt file.  I'm fairly new to VB so I'm not sure how to do If/Then statements in it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do this. If you want a macro you can use the macro recorder to record yourself performing these steps. Then edit the resultant VBA in to a reusable function that performs the operation.

First, format the cells so that the data conforms to the display you want.

- Right click the column
- Select Format Cells
- Choose "Scientific", and "4" decimal places
- Click File > Save As
- Choose File Type: `Unicode Text (*.txt)`
- Enter the name of the file
- Click Save